# Getting stuck going left with tile based collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, tilemap, roguelikes, tiles

Thanks to [Alexandre Desbiens](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102295/roguelike-2d-collision-detection) I have awesome collision detection. I can just slide right along walls. However if I try to go left into a wall I get stuck. But the good news is I can just back out and everything is okay. But it would be nice to have a consistent behavior when running into walls. Here is what my tryMove function looks like.

```
tryMove: function() {
      var game = roguelike.game;
      var speed = game.library.speedPerSecond(this.speed);
      //Left
      if(this.moving.left
        && !this.collision(speed, 0)
        && !this.collision(speed, 1)) {
        this.x -= speed;
      }
      //Up
      if(this.moving.up
        && !this.collision(0, -speed)
        && !this.collision(1, -speed)) {
        this.y -= speed;
      }
      //Right
      if(this.moving.right
        && !this.collision(speed + 1, 0)
        && !this.collision(speed + 1, 1)) {
        this.x += speed;
      }
      //down
      if(this.moving.down
        && !this.collision(0, speed + 1)
        && !this.collision(1, speed + 1)) {
        this.y += speed;
      }
    }
```

I added the second collision test to check two different points of the player one on both corners of the players moving direction. I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: What are the parameters of `collision`, and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: *collision(xOffset, yOffset)* checks a collision with walls at the player's position + the offset.

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens TBH, you should not have to answer to comments on OP's question :P (but since the op's question seems to be built on your previous answers....)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Yeah, that was I was thinking. By having a link in his question, it makes tracing previous posts easier, I guess...

Comment: Why did this question get down voted?

Comment: @zachdyer Downvoters usually don't show much, but the reason is probably included in the text when you hover the downvote button.

Comment: I guess someone thought it was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting *-speed* when doing a left or up movement and *speed* when doing a down or right movement:

```
tryMove: function() {
    var game = roguelike.game;
    var speed = game.library.speedPerSecond(this.speed);
    //Left
    if(this.moving.left
        && !this.collision(-speed, 0)) {
        this.x -= speed;
    }
    //Up
    if(this.moving.up
        && !this.collision(0, -speed)) {
        this.y -= speed;
    }
    //Right
    if(this.moving.right
        && !this.collision(speed, 0)) {
        this.x += speed;
    }
    //down
    if(this.moving.down
        && !this.collision(0, speed)) {
        this.y += speed;
    }
}
```

When doing a collision check on the X asis, going left will move your character of *-speed* pixels. You must then check the collision at the position *-speed* in order to catch any present wall.

I also have fixed the down and right collisions, you didn't need to put +1 to *speed*.

Comment: Once again Alexandre Desbiens answers my question. That was a nice catch I did not even notice that. I appreciate it much!